# Need to help how to update (not create new) test cases on testlink

Tags: testlink

I have some test cases that exists on testlink with specific ID, now I want to update some field such as: summary, precondition, steps, etc.... but I want to update automation (not manual) by import test case with valid xml file (I want to create a new version test case after import).

Answer (score 0):

You can try by exporting what is existing and Ctrl+F and update what you need and then save it and by importing as a new project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Ushani, but I want edit test cases that existed on testlink in that project (not add new project). I did it, by import xml file base on external ID and always create a new version for that test case.